# Configuring HAProxy to send X_FORWARDED_FOR and X_REAL_IP at the same time

Tags: haproxy

I'm working for company which have software based on both headers, and if one of them is missing, the software is not working properly. I find a way to configure HAProxy to send each of them but separated. I need to find solution which will make HAProxy to send both. Can I use reqadd or http-request add-header/set-header to set a the second header?